# Memory corruption in release mode visual studio

Tags: c, crash, visual-studio-2005, memory-corruption

I have a piece of code which used to crash in release mode of visual studio. Though I have fixed it, I would like to know, why the crash actually happened.

There was a piece of code written in the following way.

```
char *output = strdup(strcat(strdup(text1),strdup(text2)));
```

I know it is a ridiculous piece of code, I wonder what the person was thinking when he wrote this! But my question is why didnt the code crash at this point. It crashed after 3-4 functions where called, which had multiple mallocs and free being called.

What is the reason for a code to crash at a certain point, even though the actual memory corruption was done much earlier?

Comment: Code that crashes because of heap corruption is never the code that caused the corruption.  If you found this back in a program then you can completely count on there being a lot more of it that *does* corrupt the heap.

Comment: It didn't crash at that point because the memory corruption didn't happen to be acted upon on in any noticeable way. The question is sort of like asking, "if I lost my keys two days ago, how come I didn't notice until now?"